# how to initialize string[20] in the constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

okay so I've edited the code. theres a problem when the output screen comes up in the input data part. it takes the owner name but crashes immediately after that.(ps in the question, house should have an array of 100 obj) and i also wanted to ask that if theres a way to fix a string size so that user can only enter a name within size 20  ?

```cpp
class House
{
private: 
    string owner;
    string address;
    int bedrooms;
    float price;
public:
    
    House(string owner="", string address="", int bedrooms = 0, float price = 0.0)
    {
        this->owner = owner;
        this->address = address;
        this->bedrooms = bedrooms;
        this->price = price;

    }
    void setOwner(string owner)
    {
        this->owner = owner;
    }
    void setAddress(string address)
    {
        this->address = address;
    }
    void setBedrooms(int bedrooms)
    {
        this->bedrooms = bedrooms;
    }
    void setPrice(float price)
    {
        this->price = price;
    }
    string getOwner()
    {
        return owner;
    }
    string getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }
    int getBedrooms()
    {
        return bedrooms;
    }
    float getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    void getData()
    {
        cout << "Enter Owner : ";
        cin >> owner;
        setOwner(owner);
        cout << "Enter Addres : ";
        cin >> address;
        setAddress(address);
        cout << "Number of Bedrooms? : ";
        cin >> bedrooms;
        setBedrooms(bedrooms);
        cout << "Price : ";
        cin >> price;
        setPrice(price);
        cout << endl;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << "Owner \t Address \t Bedrooms \t Price" << endl;
        cout << getOwner() << "\t" << getAddress() << "\t" << getBedrooms() << "\t" << getPrice() << "\t" << endl;

    }
};
int main()
{

    House *h[100] ;
    
    int time=0;
    char yesorno;
    do
    {

        h[time]->getData();
        h[time]->display();
        
        cout << "Do you wish to continue ?";
        cin >> yesorno;
        time++;
    } while (yesorno == 'y' || yesorno =='Y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no classes in C.

Comment: Are you sure this is a question for C and not C++?

Comment: @codeplayer These declarations string owner[20];  string address[20]; do not make a sense. Either declare the data members as char owner[20]; char address[20];  or  like string owner; string address;

Comment: To expound, you are declaring an array of strings. Also, use default member initialization and constructor initialization sections.

Comment: Do you really want to allow for 20 owners of a house? And the house to have 20 addresses? I think each house should have 1 address.

Comment: If the max length is 20, your C-strings should probably have length 21. But that's weird and I don't see why you can't just bump all the way up to 128 at a **minimum**. That is, if you insist on using C-strings and not `std::string`. I can think of a lot of addresses that don't fit in 19 characters.

Comment: ***I get an error "no default constructor for class House"*** That is completely unrelated to your improper usage of arrays. To use `House houseinfo;` since you did not pass the required arguments the compiler asks for you to declare a default constructor: `House() `

Comment: `string owner[20];` -- Your code is confusing.  Do you mean there will be up to 20 owners per house, or do you mean a single owner can have 20 characters in the name?  If it's the latter, this declaration does not match the description.  Maybe the confusion is that you believe a `std::string` can only hold a single character?

Comment: I think your professor wants you to use c-strings instead of the proper c++ std::string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The error about not finding a default constructor is simple enough. You created **a** constructor, which took away the compiler-provided default. Then, because you don't provide a default, you get this error when you attempt to declare your object `houseinfo`.

Fixing just that error only requires a default constructor. Here's one version of your class:

```cpp
class House {
 private:
  std::string owner;
  std::string address;
  int bedrooms = 0;  // CHANGE: Default member initialization
  float price = 0.0f;  // NOTE: 0.0 is a double

 public:
  House() = default;  // CHANGE: Add default constructor

  // CHANGE: Got rid of default values in parameterized ctor
  House(std::string owner, std::string address, int bedrooms, float price)
      : owner(owner), address(address), bedrooms(bedrooms), price(price) {}
  void setOwner(std::string owner) { this->owner = owner; }
  void setAddress(std::string address) { this->address = address; }
  void setBedrooms(int bedrooms) { this->bedrooms = bedrooms; }
  void setPrice(float price) { this->price = price; }
  std::string getOwner() const { return owner; }
  std::string getAddress() const { return address; }
  int getBedrooms() const { return bedrooms; }
  float getPrice() const { return price; }
};
```

I used default member initialization, seen in the `private` section. This makes writing a default constructor trivial, as you can see in the line `House() = default;`. Both of these features require C++11.

I got rid of all the `[20]` stuff because you were using `std::string`. You were declaring an array of `std::string` objects, not a single string with capacity 20. Even if an array of strings was intended, you were also using it wrong in just about every instance.

Here's a version of the class using C-strings. It's uglier, and is missing a lot of error checking which now has to be done manually. If we really get into it, the use `strncpy()` is not considered good practice anymore, but I don't believe that C++ has provided `strlcpy()`. Generally speaking, `std::string` is going to be a lot better, as imperfect as it may be.

```cpp
class House {
 private:
  static const int arrSize = 20;
  char owner[arrSize]{0};
  char address[arrSize]{0};
  int bedrooms = 0;
  float price = 0.0f;

 public:
  House() = default;

  House(char owner[], char address[], int bedrooms, float price)
      : bedrooms(bedrooms), price(price) {
    std::strncpy(this->owner, owner, arrSize - 1);
    std::strncpy(this->address, address, arrSize - 1);
  }

  void setOwner(char owner[]) {
    std::strncpy(this->owner, owner, arrSize - 1);
  }

  void setAddress(char address[]) {
    strncpy(this->address, address, arrSize - 1);
  }
  
  void setBedrooms(int bedrooms) { this->bedrooms = bedrooms; }
  void setPrice(float price) { this->price = price; }
  const char* getOwner() const { return owner; }
  const char* getAddress() const { return address; }
  int getBedrooms() const { return bedrooms; }
  float getPrice() const { return price; }
};
```

Just so everything is addressed, I don't know what you're attempting to do in your `main()` function. Your line `h->houseinfo;` makes no sense whatsoever. I also don't know why you need an array of pointers to `House`.

Comment: I am not sure if the `arrSize` should be 20 or 21 to account for null termination. It depends on the exact wording of the homework assignment. With that said this code made it easy to change.

Comment: Good catch. I actually commented on the question that it should probably be 21. I'll leave it as is, though.